# Clothes deform after exported to fbx

Tags: rigging

I know this question sounds stupid vbut I'm new to Blender. I tried a lot of methods but the mesh keep glitching. Any help is appreciated!:P

I've recently been trying to make clothes for my character in Blender. Although everything looks perfect in Blender , the clothes deform pretty badly when I export to fbx format.

Blender file download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ksj1F6PLjsdKGyWvRTUmKXRTKPvc5WDL/view?usp=sharing

fbx file download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y1q9egngTI516Xh567-NpZAyd8-fjatx/view?usp=sharing

In Blender:
[image]

In Fbx format:
[image]

Comment: Apply its rotation. In object mode select the cloth, hit ctrl+a and select rotation.

Comment: Thx. That works perfectly for me!!